# Tomcat 6.0 service does not start: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: windows-xp, tomcat, java, tomcat6

I installed Tomcat on my Windows server but I can't get it to start. I start the service and I see the progress bar, but it fails.

I installed the Java Runtime Environment Version 6 and created JRE_HOME Environment variable. (C:\Program Files\Java\jre6)

Below is the jakarta_serviceYYYMMDD.log entries:

```
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.2.0) started
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] Running Service...
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] Starting service...
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
[2010-04-08 14:22:42] [info] : java/lang/Object
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the look of the error the Tomcat native launcher does not find the `rt.jar` file in your JRE install.

Make sure that:

- the JVM is correctly installed;
- the JRE_HOME variable points to it.

Comment: Yep.  The rt.jar file was missing for some reason.  Uninstalled and reinstalled the JRE and now Tomcat works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with Windows 7, Tomcat 7.0, and JDK 1.6.0_31.  I fixed it by changing the path to the JVM from `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`.  To do that, run `Tomcat7w.exe` from the Tomcat bin directory, switch to the Java tab, and change the Java Virtual Machine entry.

Comment: +1 Thanks.. I just had the issue today and this fixed my issue

Comment: +1 Great answer. This exact solution was what I needed to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem. rt.jar file was missing from ../JRE/lib. I copied the rt.jar file from JDK/jre/lib to /JRE/lib and Tomcat worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a file called `tomcat(4|5|6)w.exe` in your Tomcat directory? If you see one, run the file and you will get a configuration dialogue up. Check the Java tab and see if this all seems ok.

Make sure the paths to the files `jvm.dll` and `bootstrap.jar` are fine.

This works for Tomcat 4 and 5, but I'm not sure about Tomcat 6.

Answer (score -1):

A simple reinstall of Java fixes this immediatey!